# logistic and anova

Tags: logistic, fractional-factorial

In here, you can see [original data](http://www.statsci.org/data/oz/snails.html).

My data is $4\times3\times3\times2$ completely randomized design experiment data.
I want to model the probability of survival in terms of the stimulus variables.
[image]

This is my data.

[image]

1.
If I want to do logistic, the R-code for model is

```
glm_a<-glm(Deaths~Exposure+Rel.Hum+Temp+Species, data=data, family = poisson)
```

I want to know whether the poisson is right, or not.
Because the Deaths is sum of 0(survived) and 1(death).

2. If I want to do anova, the R-code is

   b<-aov(Deaths~Species+Exposure+Rel.Hum+Temp, data)

and here, can I use logit of Deaths as Y, response variable??

---

```
A<-factor(data$Species,levels=c("A","B"),labels=c(-1,1))

glm_a<-lm(Y~data$Species+data$Exposure+data$Rel.Hum+data$Temp+data$Species+data$Exposure, data=data, family = binomial)

summary(glm_a)

par(mfrow=c(2,2));plot(glm_a)

library(car)
vif(glm_a)
```

the resulf of vif is crazy!!

Comment: What do you mean with "logit of Deaths as Y"? Do you mean something like aov(log(Deaths)~Species+Exposure+Rel.Hum+Temp, data) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the first code runs a poisson regression. So if you want to change it to logistic regression you must use [the following R code](https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/glm.html):

```
glm_a<-glm(Deaths~Exposure+Rel.Hum+Temp+Species, data=data, family = binomial)
```

Since your dependent variable is binary (death yes vs. no) I would use the logistic regression instead of using the anova. This is because ANOVA assumes a [continuous dependent variable](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-apply-t-test-Anova-in-categorical-variables). Or in fact, if you have recored the time to event and censoring you could use a cox regression.

EDIT

Thank you for providing the data. I had a look at the data which indeed is kind of a summary table indicating number of deaths per condition. You could recreate the original data with this information because you know the sample size per group and the number of deaths per group. If you do so you will get data where each row contains information about one single snail (variables about the conditions and a variable whether this snail died).  Then you could use a logistic regression. Or maybe someone has an other suggestion

Comment: Thank you for comment. But as you can see the data, the Deaths is given as sum of the number of death snails. So If I put "family=binomial", it turns error because of Y variable. What should I do??

Comment: And I think, Deaths are continuous variable. If I want to find which condition is fatal to snail, isn't it better to do anova??

Comment: @hana: do you mean the summary table (2nd picture)? Don't you have the original data (your first picture)? If you have it, you should use the data from first picture were every row corresponds to one object (one living being, don't know what it is in your case). Than the dependent variable is binary

Comment: @hana: What error do yo get? But keep in mind that if your question is mainly about the code the question probably rather should go to stackoverflow

Comment: I wrote the link about my data. It was my first time to use this site, I didn't know that. And you mean, I can't use anova here?

Comment: @hana:I had a look at the data which indeed is kind of a summary table indicating number of deaths per condition. You could recreate the original data with this information because you know the sample size per group and the number of deaths per group. Then you could use a logistic regression. Or maybe someone has an other suggestion